# Laravel Policies never called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to apply a policy on a TeamController:

TeamPolicy is :

```
public function before(User $user, $ability)
{
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}


public function create(User $user, Tournament $tournament)
{
    return $user->isOwner($tournament);
}
```

In my controller I call it this way:

```
public function create(Tournament $tournament)
{
    $team = new Team;
    if (Auth::user()->cannot('create', $team)) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}
```

I dd inside both functions, but never get called.

Any idea what's wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered your policy in the AuthServiceProvider, like so: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#creating-policies ?

Comment: I totally forgot! Tx!